# "Непризнанный": слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

почему слово "непризнанный" пишется слитно?

Answer (score 7):

Потому что НЕ в данном случае - приставка, придающая противоположное значение. В соответствии с правилом: одиночные причастия пишутся с НЕ слитно, при наличии зависимого слова (кроме наречий меры и степени) или противопоставления с союзом "а" - раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

Одиночное причастие в полной форме по своим свойствам близко к прилагательному (обозначает постоянный во времени признак),  поэтому к нему применяются обычные правила: слитное написание приставки НЕ и раздельное написание отрицательной частицы НЕ. Например:непризнанный (неизвестный) талант - замена синонимом, никем не признанный - усиление отрицания, не признанный, а неизвестный - противопоставление. 
При наличии зависимых слов или краткой формы причастие начинает обозначать процессуальный признак (признак как действие), в этом случае НЕ пишется раздельно, как и с глаголами:
талант не признан, не признанный соотечественниками талант.